# Download File AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, download

I'm trying to download a file from asp.net controller ActionResult but how to download from browser ?

i'm returning File on controller level

```
  return File(pdfStream, "application/pdf", "sample.pdf");
```

on angular code

```
reportService.getReport().then(function(file){

  //how to make this file download  

})
```

i tried with this code but download a pdf only when browser is chrome but that file content empty

```
reportService.getReport().then(function (file) {
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/pdf,' + encodeURI(file);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.pdf';
    hiddenElement.click();
});
```

response header look like

[image]

any help appreciate !!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using $http.post

You can use FileSaver.js
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

And set the response type as blob.

Something like this,

```
reportService.getReport().then(function(url, data){

return $http.post(url, data, { responseType:'blob' })
                    .then(function (response) {                        
                        try {                            
                            $timeout(function () {
                                saveAs(response.data, "mypdf.pdf");                                
                            });
                        } catch (ex) {
                            console.log(ex);
                        }                                                
                    }, function (response) {
                        // error
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    });


})
```

Comment: Hi João Augusto i tried with your solution but still i can't save anything on my mvc controller i'm returning like this `return File(pdfStream, "application/pdf", "reportName.pdf");`

Comment: Do you get a json object on the response ?

Comment: yes i'm getting a json object and i have managed to solve it using your solution but problem is once i deploy application in to server. pdf download pub corrupted or can't open